# bash cycle breaks when calling ssh command in the loop

Tags: bash, ssh

The script below will break at first ssh command. Not erroring out, but breaking the while loop. Debugging the script with `set -vx` will  indicate that the `read -r line` does not read anything else from the variable being iterated.

Once I comment out the ssh line, it will work happily and iterate over the entire loop.

Can you help unravel the mystery here?

Thanks!

Script:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -vx
file_list=$(cat <<EOT
aaa
bbbb
ccccc
dddddd
eeeeeee
EOT
)

while read -r line; do
    echo ${line}
    ssh 192.168.100.222 touch /tmp/${line}
done <<< "${file_list}"
```

Output with ssh line commented (`set -vx` was left out here)

```
aaa
bbbb
ccccc
dddddd
eeeeeee
```

Output with the ssh line enabled

```
aaa
```

Comment: I also changed the ssh line with the one below and it shows it's being executed, but the while still breaks:

`ssh 192.168.100.222 echo "1"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add option `-n` to ssh to stop reading from stdin.

---

See: `man ssh`

Comment: mystery solved! So ssh is actually eating up all the rest of stdin. Thanks for clarifying that.

Answer (score 1):

Use an array instead of a string so you're just looping through array contents instead of relying one being able to read from stdin:

```
file_list=(
aaa
bbbb
ccccc
dddddd
eeeeeee
)

for file in "${file_list[@]}"; do
    echo "$file"
    ssh 192.168.100.222 touch "/tmp/$file"
done
```

To make it more robust google how best to populate an array from a list of newline-separated strings (look for `readarray`, `maparray` and `IFS=$'\n'` - I don't recall the "best" incantation off the top of my head).

Comment: Thanks for that. It seems to be working well. While this fixes my immediate issue, I am still interested in understanding why iterating like in my initial solution breaks.

Comment: Because both your loop and ssh are reading from stdin and stdin is coming from `<<< "${file_list}"`